# Would Lenipobra be killed on the orbital Vavatch in Iian M. Banks' Consider Phlebas?

Tags: the-culture

On a structure without gravity and only centripetal (centrifugal pseudo)force how could Lenipobra 'fall' to his death?

I've thought too long on this question and come to the conclusion that Lenipobra would live to die another way. (Please see [this tiresome discussion](https://ldh3790.wix.com/vavatch) for more details. :-)

When Lenipobra leaped over the railing he lost contact with the structure that was exerting the centripetal force on him. Without that there is no feeling of gravity (centrifugal pseudo force) and also there is no gravity. He would float until the curvature of the orbital brought the megaship 'up' to him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might find it useful to take the [tour] to learn more about the site.

Comment: thanks for the edit @DavidW - was very confused. My VTC reason is now technically incorrect, but will keep in place because this seems to be asking a physics question

Comment: @NKCampbell - This question is off-topic because it's asking about real-world physics, divorced from the actual content of the novel. You could just as easily ask "if I jumped from a height on a ringworld, would I fall to my death?" and have no reference to Iain Banks whatsoever

Comment: @DavidW - Your edit conceals that the link is to OPs personal website. This could be (mis?)construed as them spamming

Comment: @Valorum Ah, apologies. I did follow the link, and it seemed an honest attempt to analyse the problem.  Even the dependent links appeared legit.  You may certainly revert if it's a problem.

Comment: @DavidW - Honestly I'm not that fussed about trying to fix an off-topic question. If OP repairs it (somehow, although I'm blowed if I can work out how they'd do it), I'll revert the link to explain its source

Answer (score 4):

A Culture orbital (based on the [standard template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_(The_Culture))) would have a rotational velocity of **135km/s**.  If even 0.1% of that vector is normal to the surface at the point when our skydiver meets it, that is still 135m/s or nearly 500km/h, which would be quite fatal.

Dropping from a height of 2000km above the orbital (3.7 million km diameter), the tangent line intersects the surface approximately 86000 km away (external reference frame) at an angle of 2.66 degrees.  This translates into a normal velocity of **>6km/s**!

So yes, perhaps your analysis of the geometry is correct, but when you do the math on the relative velocities it becomes quite apparent this is a fatal misstep.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the quick analysis and reply. I'll look into rewording and reposting. However, if Lenipobra was only, say 100 m above the deck, would he be killed? I'll try some geometry and math :-)

Comment: Not to mention the CAM they used to annihilate the pieces.

Comment: @ldh1776  When Leniproba released or stepped off the gantry he immediately started to travel in a straight line parallel to the floor, while the deck directly below continued to follow a curve, accelerating toward him.  As the spin of the orbital was mimicking gravity of 1G, the deck accelerated up toward him at 1G for 100 meters.  This is the same effect as if *he* accelerated toward the *deck* at 1G.

Comment: Where's 135 km/s from?  I get about 120 km/s to get Earth gravity and Earth day length

Comment: @endolith I just rechecked my math, and using an 86400s day and g=9.802 m/s^2, I get 134 787 m/s.  Note that the Culture day and Culture standard gravity are only _approximately_ Earth's, so even 135 km/s is probably overly precise.

Comment: Oh it's because you're using 3.7 million km diameter instead of 3 million km

Comment: For reference, Vavatch was non-Culture and had 4.4 million km diameter, spun at 130 km/s (which should produce 0.8 G?) and had 20% more gravity than a normal Culture orbital, according to the book, which implies a normal Culture orbital is 0.6 G?